# Does Azure have similar feature like Firebase In-App Messaging

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am currently using Azure Notification Hub to send push notifications. I however also need to make use of in-app messaging, a feature I am only of being provided by Firebase at the moment: [Firebase In-App Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/in-app-messaging)

Does Azure/Microsoft have such a service?

Comment: You can read [Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/), hope it can help you.

Comment: @JasonPan is it available for mobile? I'm trying to find info on that in that resource.

Comment: If you have a solution, can you send out the answer and share it with everyone?

Comment: @JasonPan I did not find a solution. I will probably be going with Google's Firebase In App Messaging as it is 100% free at the moment.

Comment: You can search for the keyword `Azure Mobile Engagement`, which should be useful to you.

Comment: @JasonPan AME is no longer around it seems. Sadly

Answer (score 0):

## Newest

I found that when I clicked on the [Azure Mobile Engagement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/general-availability-azure-mobile-engagement/) link, the page jumped to the [Visual Studio App Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-center/) page.

So I searched for relevant information and hope it will be useful to you.

[Configuring App Center for Push Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/#configuring-app-center-for-push-notifications)

**PRIVIOUS**

Microsoft has `Azure Mobile Engagement`.

> Azure Mobile Engagement is now generally available. Azure Mobile Engagement has SDKs available for Apple iOS, Google Android, Windows Universal Apps, Windows Phone Apps and Apache Cordova.

[General Availability: Azure Mobile Engagement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/tag/in-app-messaging/)

Comment: Azure Mobile Engagement has been retired my friend :(
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/285737-mobile-engagement

Comment: Push Notifications and In App Messaging are rather different :)
The link you provided is for push notifications. Im after in app messaging:

https://www.kumulos.com/2019/07/22/in-app-messaging-vs-push-notifications-whats-the-difference/

Comment: @pnizzle Then there should be no such services.

Comment: Cheers for trying. Didnt know they had given that space a go before